# HighCharts Time series missing points?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, highcharts, time-series, dotnethighcharts

I use DotnetHighCharts TimeSeries in here : http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/15464#188170

I have hourly groupped data like this:

```
DATE               | DATA
11.19.2012 - 06:00 | 23
11.19.2012 - 07:00 | 12
11.19.2012 - 08:00 | 34
11.19.2012 - 09:00 | 46
11.20.2012 - 08:00 | 23
11.20.2012 - 09:00 | 78
```

there is no data between `11.19.2012 - 09:00` - `11.20.2012 - 08:00`

When I set the startPoint `11.17.2012 - 06:00` and set pointInterval `1000*60*60`.

Result:

```
DATE               | DATA
11.19.2012 - 06:00 | 23
11.19.2012 - 07:00 | 12
11.19.2012 - 08:00 | 34
11.19.2012 - 09:00 | 46
11.19.2012 - 10:00 | 23
11.19.2012 - 11:00 | 78
```

There is no data between `11.19.2012 - 09:00` - `11.20.2012 - 08:00` so shifting to the left until the data is not.

How can I set the missing values to "0". Or another way?

Comment: Need much more info than this. What are your values for those time stamps? Do you have a quick sample you could put up?

Comment: I have irregular Interval Time Data. I think, I can solve the problem with using "Time data with irregular intervals" chart? Right?

Comment: I m talking about this: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

Comment: If your data for `11.20.2012 - 08:00` and `11.20.2012 - 09:00` are 0/null then yes. Without know what the values are it is hard to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using that demo link in your comment I have created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/NsZDe/2/). I do not see what you are seeing with it missing times for 11/20/2012. Do you have a sample site or screenshot showing your issue?
Code (js):

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 10, 17, 6, 0),
                    pointInterval: 1000*60*60
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Test',
                data: [
                    [Date.UTC(2012, 10, 19, 6, 0), 23],
                    [Date.UTC(2012, 10, 19, 7, 0), 12],
                    [Date.UTC(2012, 10, 19, 8, 0), 34],
                    [Date.UTC(2012, 10, 19, 9, 0), 46],
                    [Date.UTC(2012, 10, 20, 8, 0), 23],
                    [Date.UTC(2012, 10, 20, 9, 0), 78]
                    ]}]
        });
```